# sum values in LinkedList Based on Grouping by specific year in key using Java

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, java-8

I have a linked list like below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> month = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    TreeMap<String, Integer> output = new TreeMap<>();
    month.put("May2021", 1);
    month.put("May2022", 1);
    month.put("Oct2022", 2);
    month.put("Oct2020", 1);
    month.put("Oct2021", 2);
    month.put("Jan2021", 1);
    month.put("Jan2022", 4);
    month.put("Aug2021", 1);
    month.put("Aug2022", 3);
    month.put("Aug2020", 4);
    month.put("Nov2021", 8);
    month.put("Dec2021", 1);
    month.put("Dec2020", 2);
    month.put("Nov2020", 5);
    month.put("Mar2021", 1);
    month.put("Mar2022", 1);
    month.put("Jul2022", 1);
    month.put("Jul2021", 2);
    month.put("Feb2021", 1);
    month.put("Feb2022", 1);
    month.put("Apr2022", 1);
    month.put("Apr2021", 1);
    month.put("Jun2022", 1);
    month.put("Jun2021", 1);
    month.put("Sep2020", 6);
    month.put("Sep2021", 1);
    month.put("Sep2022", 1);
```

I need the output as a treemap as shown below - provided the below conditions are met,

```
    // 2020 Should have sum of fiscal years starting Feb2020 to Jan2021
    // 2021 Should have sum of fiscal years starting Feb2021 to Jan2022
    // 2022 Should have sum of fiscal years starting Feb2022 to Jan2023
    /*
    { "2020" :18 },
    { "2021" :25 },
    { "2022" :35 }
```

It should match all the conditions above.

I have tried like this, but i am finding difficulties to achieve the result. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        month.entrySet().forEach(monthYear -> {
        String[] splitMonthYear = monthYear.getKey().split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
        String fullMonth = splitMonthYear[0];
        String fullYear = splitMonthYear[1];

        if (fullMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("jan")) {
            output.put(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(fullYear) - 1), monthYear);
        } else {
            output.put(fullYear, monthYear);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution using `for` loop.

```
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> output = new TreeMap<>();
for(String key : month.keySet()){
    String mon = key.substring(0,3);
    int val = Integer.parseInt(key.substring(3));
            
    if(mon.equals("Jan")){
        output.put(val-1, output.getOrDefault(val-1, 0)+month.get(key));
    }else{
        output.put(val, output.getOrDefault(val, 0)+month.get(key));
    }
}
```

As others mentioned, output would be
`{2020=19, 2021=24, 2022=12}`

Answer (score 1):

According to this logic:

```
    // 2020 Should have sum of fiscal years starting Feb2020 to Jan2021
    // 2021 Should have sum of fiscal years starting Feb2021 to Jan2022
    // 2022 Should have sum of fiscal years starting Feb2022 to Jan2023
```

This **shouldnt be** the answer:

```
    { "2020" :18 },
    { "2021" :25 },
    { "2022" :35 }
```

Rather it should be(for the given input):

```
    { "2020" :19 },
    { "2021" :24 },
    { "2022" :12 }
```

which can be achieved using this simple technique: (instead of using complicated regex and all)

```
month.forEach((key,val) -> {
      String year = "";
      if(key.substring(0,3).equalsIgnoreCase("jan")){
        year = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(key.substring(3)) -1);
      }else{
        year = key.substring(3);
      }
      if(output.containsKey(year)){
        output.put(year,output.get(year) + val);
      }else{
        output.put(year,val);
      }
    });
```

**Algorithm is** ::

- Check if the month is Jan. if so , the year should be 1 less (coz that's what the question says).
- Parse the year (which is just the last 4 characters of the strings) and subtract that 1 (if required) and then put in your Treemap.
- If entry already exists in treemap, simply add it to the existing value to get cumulative sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collectors.groupingBy` to group the stream elements by a key. The key is determined by the `getYearToGroupUnder` method whose logic is same as yours (Note: The regex might be simplified).

By using `Collectors.summingInt` as a downstream collector, we sum up the values of all map entries that gets mapped to the *same key*.

```
output = month.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> getYearToGroupUnder(e.getKey()),
                    TreeMap::new,
                    Collectors.summingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)));


private static String getYearToGroupUnder(String monthYear) {
    String[] splitMonthYear = monthYear.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
    String fullMonth = splitMonthYear[0];
    String fullYear = splitMonthYear[1];

    return fullMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("jan") 
                ? String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(fullYear) - 1)
                : fullYear;
}
```

This is the result (seems your expected result is wrong for the data you have posted)

```
{2020=19, 2021=24, 2022=12}
```